# 2-byte signed comparision

Tags: assembly, 6502

I'm working on comparing 2-byte signed integers and I feel like I'm on the right track, but I must be missing something. I've rewritten the same algorithm from scratch a few different times and all of them get close but don't work for all the cases I'm testing. Here's my latest version:

```
MATH_lt_int: ; a < b, a: MATH_INT_INPUT_1, b: MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  jsr MATH_clear_int_output ; I use too many subroutines, sorry.
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1
  eor MATH_INT_INPUT_2 + 1
  bmi @different_sign ; eor our high bytes and check
                      ; the neg flag to see if they differ
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1 ; if one is positive here, they both must be
  bpl @both_positive
@both_negative: ; we have to do an inverted comparison here
                ; because if a < b then -b < -a
  sec
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1 ; check high byte first
  cmp MATH_INT_INPUT_2 + 1
  bcc @not_less_than ; inverted because negative
  sec
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 ; low byte next
  cmp MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  ; the problem seems to be somewhere around here
  bcc @not_less_than ; inverted because negative
  beq @not_less_than
  jmp @less_than ; inverted because negative
@both_positive: ; we get to do a straight-up comparison here
  sec
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1 ; check high byte first
  cmp MATH_INT_INPUT_2 + 1
  bcc @less_than
  sec
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 ; low byte next
  cmp MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  bcc @less_than
  jmp @not_less_than
@different_sign: ; if they have different signs, the negative one is smaller
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1
  bmi @less_than ; are we the negative one? Than we're @less_than
  jmp @not_less_than
@less_than:
  lda #1
  jmp @return
@not_less_than:
  lda #0
@return:
  sta MATH_INT_OUTPUT
  ; return
  rts
```

Test results:

```
50<50==0   => 0
50<60==1   => 1
60<50==0   => 0
-50<-60==0 => 1
-60<-50==1 => 1
```

So I'm currently missing it in the case where a>b and a and b are negative. That should be a 0 but it is a 1. So specifically, something must be wrong about what I'm doing in and around the second line containing `bcc @not_less_than` within the `@both_negative` section, but I can't see what's wrong with it.

Update
Thanks to @penguin359 I was able to shorten the code to this with the same level of functionality, but unfortunately it still doesn't correctly handle negative numbers:

```
MATH_lt_int: ; a < b, a: MATH_INT_INPUT_1, b: MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  jsr MATH_clear_int_output ; I use too many subroutines, sorry.
  sec
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1 ; check high byte first
  cmp MATH_INT_INPUT_2 + 1
  bmi @less_than
  sec
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 ; low byte next
  cmp MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  bmi @less_than
  jmp @not_less_than
@less_than:
  lda #1
  jmp @return
@not_less_than:
  lda #0
@return:
  sta MATH_INT_OUTPUT
  ; return
  rts
```

Test results:

```
50<50==0   => 0
50<60==1   => 1
60<50==0   => 0
-50<-60==0 => 0
-60<-50==1 => 0
```

Comment: Verify you are running this code with the given inputs because it seems quite unlikely that the last two cases can produce the same result. Anyway, you don't need to reverse the conditions because two's complement preserves the ordering. PS: the 16 bit path is broken because you must only compare the low bytes if the high bytes are equal.

Comment: I... I wasn't running the actual test the second time, so the penultimate result was already just being repeated. I hereby retire from programming. 

For at least, like, 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the compare instructions for signed integers for the high-byte. `bcc` and friends is for branched compares on unsigned integers. `bmi` is the signed version of it.

http://6502.org/tutorials/compare_instructions.html

For the high-byte, you just stick to the `bpl`, `bmi`, and `beq` branch instructions, then it will compare signed integers as expected. There's no need to worry about handling negative numbers differently. If the high-byte proves equal, then you need to compare the low-byte, but in this case, you want the unsigned version of the instructions as there's no sign bit to deal with.

Think about some simple, easy example. Let's compare 1 and 2 stored in 16-bit words. The high bytes will both be 0x00 and equal, but the low bytes will be 0x01 and 0x02. An unsigned compare says that the latter is greater. Let's push it to the extreme case of this and compare 0 with 255. The high-byte is still 0x00 in both cases, but the low bytes are now 0x00 and 0xff. Obviously, a signed compare here would consider the latter lower and representing -1, but an unsigned compare will say it's greater. If we push it to 256, well, the high bytes are no longer equal and the signed compare there works as before.

Now, let's look at negatives and compare -1 (0xffff) and -2 (0xfffe). Well, the high bytes are equal, but the low bytes are 0xff and 0xfe with -1 being greater as it should be in unsigned world. Comparing it with -256 (0xff00) and -255 (0xff01), 0x00 is less than 0x01, as well as less than 0xfe and 0xff for the -2 and -1 case. Only the high byte needs a signed comparison.

Comment: Okay! So I deleted the @both_negative and @different_sign sections, and I'm just using @both_positive but with `bmi` as the main operation for branching. Unfortunately, I'm still getting weird results for the negative test equations. Instead of them both returning 1 like they were before, they're both returning 0. I'll edit the question to show the revised code.

Comment: @JShoe Sorry, I missed the low-byte part of the code. That needs to be unsigned. I've clarified my anwer with more details, but there's still no need to treat negative differently.

Comment: Isn't `bpl` / `bmi` just based on the sign of the result, even if there was signed overflow?  So you can't *just* use that unless you've already checked that the inputs have the same sign, as in Jester's first version.  (This is the reason x86 branch conditions (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc) like `jge` are `SF=OF`, which is SF = 0 (non-negative result) for the no-overflow case, or SF=1 for the overflow case (overflow to negative when the mathematical result was positive from `x-y`).

Comment: So 6502 `bmi` is significantly different from `bcc` for signed, else you could just `bmi` after `sub`(or `cmp`)/`sbc` to do 16-bit math setting flags according to the 16-bit subtraction result, the way you can for unsigned compares with `bcc`.  (ping @JShoe)

Comment: You would need a `cmp` instruction shortly before using the conditional branch instruction `bmi`, but that is also true for the unsigned comparision with `bcc`. So it would just be a `cmp` (or `cpx`/`cpy`) of the high-byte, `bmi` and `beq`. On the `beq` branch, you'd do an additional `cmp` on the low-byte with a corresponding `bcc` or `beq` if you need to test for exact equality. No need to test for the same sign before using them.

Comment: `For the high-byte, you just stick to the bpl, bmi, and beq branch instructions, then it will compare signed integers as expected.` ORLY? Then compare -128 to +127.  0x80-0x7F = 0x01 while -128-127=-255 and 'bpl/bmi' fails.

Comment: @penguin359: Didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me. It seems you missed the point of my first comment, that `bmi` only works as a signed-less-than if you have limited-range or same-sign numbers so there isn't signed overflow.  See lvd's example. Yes you might just branch on the high half as an early-out for signed or unsigned, but you don't have to, see GCC code-gen for 64-bit compare on 32-bit ARM with `cmp`/`sbc`: https://godbolt.org/z/8TGWP5WWa  (`sbcs` means sub-with-carry and Set flags). Also included a demo of 1-register-width signed compare vs. sub and check sign differing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Darn, it's been too long since I've worked at this level. I'm remembering now it's not the negative flag, but the signed-overflow flag like found on x86 that achieves this behavior. The 6502 does have an overflow flag but it seems to be special and doesn't work as a signed-overflow for cmp/sub instructions. Yes, I don't think my example handles this correctly. It only works if it doesn't overflow the range. Carry is still fine for the low-byte once you've determined the high-byte is equal.

Comment: Right, as I commented originally, the condition you want is `SF != OF` or `SF == OF` like x86's `jl` or `jge`.  Or do like the OP or Jester's answer and rule out the possibility of signed overflow (same sign) so just the sign flag (`bmi`) works.  And yes, the low half is unsigned so the carry flag is what you want for that.

Answer (score 1):

In the same sign case, just do a 16 bit subtraction and check the result sign.

```
MATH_lt_int: ; a < b, a: MATH_INT_INPUT_1, b: MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  jsr MATH_clear_int_output ; I use too many subroutines, sorry.
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1
  eor MATH_INT_INPUT_2 + 1
  bmi @different_sign ; eor our high bytes and check
                  ; the neg flag to see if they differ
  sec
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 ; check low byte first
  sbc MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1 ; check high byte next
  sbc MATH_INT_INPUT_2 + 1
  bpl @not_less_than
  jmp @less_than
@different_sign: ; if they have different signs, the negative one is smaller
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1
  bpl @not_less_than
@less_than:
  lda #1
  jmp @return
@not_less_than:
  lda #0
@return:
  sta MATH_INT_OUTPUT
  ; return
  rts
```

A branchless version that basically emulates 17 bit sign extension could look like:

```
MATH_lt_int: ; a < b, a: MATH_INT_INPUT_1, b: MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  jsr MATH_clear_int_output ; I use too many subroutines, sorry.
  sec
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 ; check low byte first
  sbc MATH_INT_INPUT_2
  lda MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1 ; check high byte next
  sbc MATH_INT_INPUT_2 + 1
  ror ; bring carry back into MSB as 17th bit
  eor #$80 ; carry reversed during subtraction
  eor MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1 ; reuse MSB emulating sign extension
  eor MATH_INT_INPUT_2 + 1 ; and perform the 1 bit subtraction
  rol ; bring sign bit into carry
  rol ; then LSB
  and #1
  sta MATH_INT_OUTPUT
  rts
```

Comment: Is there a cheap way to shift or rotate the sign bit to the bottom of the accumulator and just return that instead of branching?  i.e. `return (uint16_t)input1 >> 15` in the different-sign case instead of branching.  Like a rotate if 6502 has that, with an and-immediate.  But yeah, this strategy should work; at first I was thinking that checking the sign after subtraction only works if there's no signed-overflow.  But that's why you're checking for same sign first, to rule that out.  You could optimize it away if you had limited-range numbers such that `|x - y| <= INT16_MAX`

Comment: Single bit rotate through carry only. So probably `ROL`/`ROL`/`AND #1`

Comment: I was afraid of that. And I don't think we can `add MATH_INT_INPUT_1 + 1` or something to load + set Carry usefully.  We know the accumulator's MSB is set, so `add` would definitely set Carry if the byte has its MSB set.  But it could also set it via `-1 + 1` false positive.  Load `0x80` into the accumulator before `add mem` / `rol` / `and`?  Nope, that's still 4 instructions, not better than rol/rol/and, and two of them still have immediate operands.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing *signed* numbers by looking only at the resulting sign is completely *incorrect*. Just look at the attempt to subtract +127 from -128, where the result should be -255 but since it does not fit in 8 bit, you get only +1 and a wrong sign.

More advanced CPUs like 68000 have special branch instructions, that is `bgt/bge/blt/ble` that correctly report whether the result of addition or subtraction, reflected in flags, was actually positive or negative. This is done in hardware by looking at "overflow XOR sign" combination of flags, so you can implement the similar strategy purely in software.

However, there is a simpler way: just invert higher (sign) bits of your numbers and compare them afterwards as unsigned quantities. You'll get the correct result for the former signed values. This works because such higher bit inversion moves signed -128..+127 interval to unsigned 0..+255 one.

Comment: For the record, it *does* work in the context of the OP's strategy (or Jester's answer), where you're eliminated the possibility of signed overflow by only subtracting numbers with the same sign.  But indeed, penguin359's answer currently seems to be suggesting doing just cmp/bmi on the high byte first.

Answer (score 0):

Look this article:

Beyond 8-bit Unsigned Comparisons by Bruce Clark

http://6502.org/tutorials/compare_beyond.html

"The 6502 has several options available for comparing numbers. Each option, naturally, has its pros and cons in terms of speed and size. There are also some infrequently used options that occasionally come in handy. Finally, and unfortunately, some misconceptions abound about signed (twos complement) numbers and the correct way to compare them. All of these topics will be covered below."

Look on section 5 "SIGNED COMPARISONS"